# GridView to make square board

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I'm trying to make a square board with 5 x 5 grid using gridview. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/squareBoard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="5"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Adapter I used:

```
private class TextViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mWidth, mHeight;

    public TextViewAdapter(Context c, int width, int height) {
        mContext = c;
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mWidth * mHeight;
    }

    public TextView getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = null;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setText("" + position);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            tv.setWidth(100);
            tv.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.letter_box));
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        return tv;
    }
}
```

and this is the letter_box.xml of the textview background

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white" >
    </solid>

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" >
    </stroke>
</shape>
```

So far, i managed to display boxes, but there's always horizontal space between columns. I want them to be like a chess board.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own class `MyGridView` which extends `GridView`.

Override its `onMeasure(...)` method and set height == width, like so:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```

Then, create your own `GridViewItem` extending a `View` subclass e.g. `TextView` or `ImageView` etc. Override its `onMeasure(...)` method in the same way.

`MyGridView`and its items will all appear square.

Comment: I did slightly different though. Instead of extend the Gridview, I extend the textview. Thanks Gunnar Karlsson. u save my day!

Answer (score -1):

On your GridView, you can set the vertical spacing and the horizontal spacing that is between two items. Try setting those to 0dp.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/squareBoard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
/>
```